# how to change default username/email for authors field when bower init

Tags: bower

Trivial but a bit anoying problem.
There's following prompt during bower init:
? authors: (xyz )
Wonder how bower got this value and how to change it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It gets it from whatever you have configured for your Git, usually a user config file is located at `~/.gitconfig` containing info such as username and email.

More specifically, internally it runs the following command in order to get your username:

```
git config --get --global user.name
```

You can see the relevant part of the code on their Github:

https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/commands/init.js#L138

Comment: Following your explanation, have located .gitconfig and edited it. Also will try to find answers from source code  in the future. Thanks.